# 正規表現を用いた特定文字列を改行のみに置換

Tags: batch-file, vbs

環境はwin機だけで実現できるもので考えています。

```
target:.
├─D
├─Dow
├─M
│  └─Sample
│  └─SampleP
├─Rec
│  └─Sample
└─Vi
    └─Sample
　　　    └─Sam
```

ツリー表示したときにこのようになっていて、それぞれのフォルダ内に「*.txt」が存在します。
ファイルに記述される「AAA:」を含む行を削除し、改行のみにしたいと考えています。

batファイルで考えていましたがとても難しいためvbsやWSHで可能なのか、
どういう手順で実現できるか教えていただくと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

文字コードが決まっているならばPowershellで行けそうです。

下記のコードでは`C:\target`以下の*.txtファイルのAAA:から始まる行を全て削除して、UTF-8で保存します。

```
$root = "C:\target" #置換対象フォルダ
ls $root -Recurse  -Include *.txt | %{ $f = $_.FullName; $(Get-Content $f) -replace "^AAA:.*$", "" | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $f }
```

上記スクリプトを実行すると、下記テキストの1行目から3
行目が空白行に変換されます。

> aaa:
>   AAA:
>   AAA:B
>   AAB:

Comment: 解答いただきありがとうございます。AAA:の後に不定長の文字が入りますがそれも消して改行のみにしたいと考えています。

Comment: 質問を読み間違えていました。内容に合わせて回答の正規表現を変更しました。

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7以降に標準でインストールされているPowerShellをお勧めします。

```
foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem . -Include *.txt -Recurse) {
    @(Get-Content $f) -replace ".*AAA:.*", "" | Set-Content $f
}
```